# Display figure/img 100 width when Bootstrap 5 float classes (float-sm-start / float-sm-end) removed at breakpoint

Tags: css, css-float, bootstrap-5, figure

I'm updating my HTML files to Bootstrap version 5.2.3.

In the current version (4.6.2.) I'm using the float classes left and right to position images with text wrapped on their respective sides. I also have the figures to take up 40% of horizontal screen space until the breakpoint. This prevent the text wrapping the image becoming very narrow just before the breakpoint. I also have some margins between the figures and wrapping text.  I accomplished this using the following CSS:

```
figure img {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
}

figure.float-left {
  margin-right: 1.25rem;
}

figure.float-right {
  margin-left: 1.25rem;
}

.float-left {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
}

figure figcaption {
  text-align: left;
}

/*== Remove float classes on medium devices and smaller ==*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 575.98px) {

  .float-left,
  .float-right {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Below the breakpoint the figure is display full width with their respective left or right margins removed.

I want to accomplish this also in the Bootstrap 5.2.3 version of my pages. I use the `float-sm-start` and `float-sm-end` classes for this.

Without additional CSS there are no margins between the figures and wrapping text. Moreover, if I decrease screen size the text wrapping the figure becomes very narrow just before the breakpoint, as shown in figure 1.[image: narrow wrapping text before breakpoint]. The figures also don't take up 40% of horizontal screen space.

I can somewhat recreate what I want by using the following CSS:

```
figure.float-sm-start {
  margin-right: 1.25rem;
}

figure.float-sm-end {
  margin-left: 1.25rem;
}

.float-sm-start{
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}

.float-sm-end {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
}


/*== Remove float classes on small screen sizes devices and smaller ==*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 575.98px) {

  .float-sm-start,
  .float-sm-end {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0
  }
}
```

This does the job partially, the narrow text wrapping is prevented. However, the float-end figure still has is margin-left resulting in the figure being positioned offset, as shown in figure 2 [image: float-end offset]

Is there a more elegant way to accomplish what I want by using specific utility classes? Or do I have to resort to CSS for this? And what about the other float utilities like float-md|lg|xl|xxl-start/end? Do I have to add CSS for those separately if I want them to also display this behaviour?

```css
/*Floats*/

figure.float-sm-start {
  margin-right: 1.25rem;
}

figure.float-sm-end {
  margin-left: 1.25rem;
}

.float-sm-start{
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}

.float-sm-end {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
}


/*== Remove float classes on small screen sizes devices and smaller ==*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 575.98px) {

  .float-sm-start,
  .float-sm-end {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0
  }
}


/* ===== Images ===== */
/* Set Images to Resize by Default */
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
<!--Start figure-->
<figure class="float-sm-start shadow p-2 me-4 mb-3">
  <div style="overflow:hidden">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/10720924/600x450" class="" alt="Natural landscape">
  </div>
  <figcaption><strong>Afbeelding x.</strong>&#32;A random landscape photograph from Jocelyn Traher's collection on
    <a href="https://unsplash.com/collections/10720924/landscape" target="_blank">Unsplash</a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<p>Floating image to the left with text wrapping around it. You can replace the image and text with your own. The text area below the image can be used to include a caption, which describes the important content displayed in the image. </p>
<p>The <code>float</code> class (<code>float-sm-start</code>) starts on viewports sized SM (small) or wider (≥576px, small breakpoint). On smaller sreen sizes the image is positioned above the text.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aufidio, praetorio, erudito homine, oculis capto, saepe audiebam, cum se lucis magis quam utilitatis desiderio moveri diceret. Videsne ut, quibus summa est in voluptate.</p>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<!--End figure-->

<hr>

<!--Start figure-->
<figure class="float-sm-end shadow p-2 ms-4 mb-3">
  <div style="overflow:hidden">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/10720924/600x450" class="" alt="Natural landscape">
  </div>
  <figcaption><strong>Afbeelding x.</strong>&#32;A random landscape photograph from Jocelyn Traher's collection on
    <a href="https://unsplash.com/collections/10720924/landscape" target="_blank">Unsplash</a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<p>Floating image to the right with text wrapping around it. You can replace the image and text with your own. The text area below the image can be used to include a caption, which describes the important content displayed in the image. </p>
<p>The <code>float</code> class (<code>float-sm-end</code>) starts on viewports sized SM (small) or wider (≥576px, small breakpoint). On smaller sreen sizes the image is positioned above the text.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aufidio, praetorio, erudito homine, oculis capto, saepe audiebam, cum se lucis magis quam utilitatis desiderio moveri diceret. Videsne ut, quibus summa est in voluptate.</p>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<!--End figure-->

<hr>
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Rob You're spot on! Don't know how to closing slash ended up there.

Answer (score 0):

Although, adding `!important` isn't always described as nice and clean, adding this solved my problem.

I added

```
/*== Remove float classes on small screen sizes devices and smaller ==*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 575.98px) {

  .float-sm-start,
  .float-sm-end {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:0 !important;
    margin-right:0 !important;
  }
}
```

to my CSS. Now both floats (start/end) have their margins removed below their breakpoint rendering both figures 100 width with no margins.

```css
/*Floats*/

figure.float-sm-start {
  margin-right: 1.25rem;
}

figure.float-sm-end {
  margin-left: 1.25rem;
}

.float-sm-start{
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}

.float-sm-end {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
}


/*== Remove float classes on small screen sizes devices and smaller ==*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 575.98px) {

  .float-sm-start,
  .float-sm-end {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:0 !important;
    margin-right:0 !important
  }
}


/* ===== Images ===== */
/* Set Images to Resize by Default */
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
<!--Start figure-->
<figure class="float-sm-start shadow p-2 me-4 mb-3">
  <div style="overflow:hidden">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/10720924/600x450" class="" alt="Natural landscape">
  </div>
  <figcaption><strong>Afbeelding x.</strong>&#32;A random landscape photograph from Jocelyn Traher's collection on
    <a href="https://unsplash.com/collections/10720924/landscape" target="_blank">Unsplash</a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<p>Floating image to the left with text wrapping around it. You can replace the image and text with your own. The text area below the image can be used to include a caption, which describes the important content displayed in the image. </p>
<p>The <code>float</code> class (<code>float-sm-start</code>) starts on viewports sized SM (small) or wider (≥576px, small breakpoint). On smaller sreen sizes the image is positioned above the text.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aufidio, praetorio, erudito homine, oculis capto, saepe audiebam, cum se lucis magis quam utilitatis desiderio moveri diceret. Videsne ut, quibus summa est in voluptate.</p>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<!--End figure-->

<hr>

<!--Start figure-->
<figure class="float-sm-end shadow p-2 ms-4 mb-3">
  <div style="overflow:hidden">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/10720924/600x450" class="" alt="Natural landscape">
  </div>
  <figcaption><strong>Afbeelding x.</strong>&#32;A random landscape photograph from Jocelyn Traher's collection on
    <a href="https://unsplash.com/collections/10720924/landscape" target="_blank">Unsplash</a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<p>Floating image to the right with text wrapping around it. You can replace the image and text with your own. The text area below the image can be used to include a caption, which describes the important content displayed in the image. </p>
<p>The <code>float</code> class (<code>float-sm-end</code>) starts on viewports sized SM (small) or wider (≥576px, small breakpoint). On smaller sreen sizes the image is positioned above the text.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aufidio, praetorio, erudito homine, oculis capto, saepe audiebam, cum se lucis magis quam utilitatis desiderio moveri diceret. Videsne ut, quibus summa est in voluptate.</p>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<!--End figure-->

<hr>
```

```css
/*Floats*/

figure.float-sm-start {
  margin-right: 1.25rem;
}

figure.float-sm-end {
  margin-left: 1.25rem;
}

.float-sm-start{
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}

.float-sm-end {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
}


/*== Remove float classes on small screen sizes devices and smaller ==*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 575.98px) {

  .float-sm-start,
  .float-sm-end {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0
  }
}


/* ===== Images ===== */
/* Set Images to Resize by Default */
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
<!--Start figure-->
<figure class="float-sm-start shadow p-2 me-4 mb-3">
  <div style="overflow:hidden">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/10720924/600x450" class="" alt="Natural landscape">
  </div>
  <figcaption><strong>Afbeelding x.</strong>&#32;A random landscape photograph from Jocelyn Traher's collection on
    <a href="https://unsplash.com/collections/10720924/landscape" target="_blank">Unsplash</a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<p>Floating image to the left with text wrapping around it. You can replace the image and text with your own. The text area below the image can be used to include a caption, which describes the important content displayed in the image. </p>
<p>The <code>float</code> class (<code>float-sm-start</code>) starts on viewports sized SM (small) or wider (≥576px, small breakpoint). On smaller sreen sizes the image is positioned above the text.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aufidio, praetorio, erudito homine, oculis capto, saepe audiebam, cum se lucis magis quam utilitatis desiderio moveri diceret. Videsne ut, quibus summa est in voluptate.</p>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<!--End figure-->

<hr>

<!--Start figure-->
<figure class="float-sm-end shadow p-2 ms-4 mb-3">
  <div style="overflow:hidden">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/10720924/600x450" class="" alt="Natural landscape">
  </div>
  <figcaption><strong>Afbeelding x.</strong>&#32;A random landscape photograph from Jocelyn Traher's collection on
    <a href="https://unsplash.com/collections/10720924/landscape" target="_blank">Unsplash</a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<p>Floating image to the right with text wrapping around it. You can replace the image and text with your own. The text area below the image can be used to include a caption, which describes the important content displayed in the image. </p>
<p>The <code>float</code> class (<code>float-sm-end</code>) starts on viewports sized SM (small) or wider (≥576px, small breakpoint). On smaller sreen sizes the image is positioned above the text.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aufidio, praetorio, erudito homine, oculis capto, saepe audiebam, cum se lucis magis quam utilitatis desiderio moveri diceret. Videsne ut, quibus summa est in voluptate.</p>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<!--End figure-->

<hr>
```

```css
/*Floats*/

figure.float-sm-start {
  margin-right: 1.25rem;
}

figure.float-sm-end {
  margin-left: 1.25rem;
}

.float-sm-start{
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}

.float-sm-end {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
}


/*== Remove float classes on small screen sizes devices and smaller ==*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 575.98px) {

  .float-sm-start,
  .float-sm-end {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0
  }
}


/* ===== Images ===== */
/* Set Images to Resize by Default */
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
<!--Start figure-->
<figure class="float-sm-start shadow p-2 me-4 mb-3">
  <div style="overflow:hidden">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/10720924/600x450" class="" alt="Natural landscape">
  </div>
  <figcaption><strong>Afbeelding x.</strong>&#32;A random landscape photograph from Jocelyn Traher's collection on
    <a href="https://unsplash.com/collections/10720924/landscape" target="_blank">Unsplash</a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<p>Floating image to the left with text wrapping around it. You can replace the image and text with your own. The text area below the image can be used to include a caption, which describes the important content displayed in the image. </p>
<p>The <code>float</code> class (<code>float-sm-start</code>) starts on viewports sized SM (small) or wider (≥576px, small breakpoint). On smaller sreen sizes the image is positioned above the text.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aufidio, praetorio, erudito homine, oculis capto, saepe audiebam, cum se lucis magis quam utilitatis desiderio moveri diceret. Videsne ut, quibus summa est in voluptate.</p>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<!--End figure-->

<hr>

<!--Start figure-->
<figure class="float-sm-end shadow p-2 ms-4 mb-3">
  <div style="overflow:hidden">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/10720924/600x450" class="" alt="Natural landscape">
  </div>
  <figcaption><strong>Afbeelding x.</strong>&#32;A random landscape photograph from Jocelyn Traher's collection on
    <a href="https://unsplash.com/collections/10720924/landscape" target="_blank">Unsplash</a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<p>Floating image to the right with text wrapping around it. You can replace the image and text with your own. The text area below the image can be used to include a caption, which describes the important content displayed in the image. </p>
<p>The <code>float</code> class (<code>float-sm-end</code>) starts on viewports sized SM (small) or wider (≥576px, small breakpoint). On smaller sreen sizes the image is positioned above the text.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aufidio, praetorio, erudito homine, oculis capto, saepe audiebam, cum se lucis magis quam utilitatis desiderio moveri diceret. Videsne ut, quibus summa est in voluptate.</p>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<!--End figure-->

<hr>
```